# Why is this XML Schema element not correct?

Tags: enums, restriction

This is an excerpt from my schema:

```
  <xs:simpleType name="atypes.priorities">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:enumeration value="low" />
  <xs:enumeration value="standard" />
  <xs:enumeration value="normal" />
  <xs:enumeration value="high" />
  <xs:enumeration value="critical" />
  <xs:pattern value="[0-9]+" />
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

When loading the schema in my XML editor (I am using XML Pad 3.0), I get the following validation error:

"Element value 'low' is not the value space of the base type, string"

Could someone explain this error to me? After all, 'low' looks like  a string to me.

How do I correct this? Basically, my simple type should be either consist of digits, or be one of the words low, normal, high and critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pattern restriction (regular expression) you say only numbers are allowed. Maybe removing that restriction will help.

Or try changing it into:
    `<xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" />`